# Whats the difference between recursion and class instance recursion

Tags: recursion, computer-science

I'll be honest, I am not sure of the terms I used in the title.

Basically I was curious to know the difference between something like:

```
class MyRecursiveClass
{
public:
     int myData;
     MyRecursiveClass* nextInLine;
     int myRecursiveFunction(int data)
     {
          data+=myData;
          if(nextInLine == null)
               return data;
          else
               return nextInLine->myRecursiveFunction(data);

     }
}
```

and

```
int staticRecursiveFunction(MyRecursiveClass* target, int currentData)
{
     if(target == null)
         return currentData;
     currentData+=target->myData;
     staticRecursiveFunction(target->nextInLine, currentData);
}
```

or

```
int otherStaticRecursiveFunction(MyRecursiveClass* target)
{
     if(target == null)
         return 0;
     return target->myData + otherStaticRecursiveFunction(target->nextInLine);
}
```

Basically what I want is the differences in overhead, as well as better terms for the difference between the two methodologies (I was at a loss when I tried to Google)

Also, any personal opinions and or preferences. I was taught recursion more as a tool to get a job done, and would like to hear professional(and amateur) opinions.

Also good readings on recursive structures/methodologies would be appreciated, though that is not the purpose of this site(more so I don't keep asking potentially dumb questions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any difference between the two except that in one case you are calling a static method, and in the other an instance method.

As far as recursion as a technique goes, this makes no difference. This seems to be more about  using object-oriented versus procedural programming (and recursion is equally applicable to both).

As for call overhead, calling an instance/virtual method is probably a bit slower on most systems because of the dispatch that has to take place, but that cannot be significant in the grand scheme of things. (If the cost for method calls is a concern, you may want to move away from recursions completely and unwind it into a loop).

Comment: This had been my assumption, but assumption is the mother of all...well you know how the saying goes. I remember my Data Structures Instructor always using the latter method, even when dealing with trees/lists/hashes/sorts etc. The only time I have ever been forced to use one method or the other has been when I "needed" to utilize private data in a class. I was wondering if there were other situations in which one was more appropriate than the other, as apposed to one's personal preference.